# Compile Error: line 5:20 no viable alternative at character '"' at line 5 column 20

Tags: apex, trigger, validation, duplicate-management

I've written the below trigger but get this error:

> Compile Error: line 5:20 no viable alternative at character '"' at line 5 column 20

What's wrong with my code? How can I fix it?

```
trigger AccountDuplicateTrigger on Account (before insert, before update)
{
    for(Account a:Trigger.new)
    {
        List<Account> acc= "Select id from Account where Name=:a.Name and Rating=:a.Rating";
        if(acc.size()>0)
        {
            acc.Name.addError('You Cannot Create the Duplicate Account');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use single quotes to declare strings, not double quotes. But in this case, you actually need square brackets (`[]`) to perform your query.

```
List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name=:a.Name AND Rating=:a.Rating];
```

That will get your code to compile. You still need to bulkify, however. You might consider just using out of the box [Duplicate Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0), which doesn't require code. Another option that will allow you to implement this validation without code is to create a unique text field and concatenate `Name` and `Rating` into it. You'll have to data load to backfill already existing records, however.

One other compile error you will hit is that you are trying to reference `acc.Name` instead of `a.Name`, where `acc` is a `List<Account>`, which does not have a `Name` attribute. Instead, you need to add the error to the `Name` field on the single `Account` record that is your loop variable (`a`).

Comment: That did work. thanks! but I have encountered a new error called Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Account> at line 8 column 2. Any idea why?

Comment: @SFDCLearner You need to add the error to the loop variable, not the list. See my updated answer.